# Jhipster - React Routing Issue

Tags: react-router, jhipster

I have developed a few react webapps using Jhipster. Recently, I tried to start a new project. I cannot get new routes to load any of my components. This is something that I have been able to do very easily in the past (as earlier as two months ago). The page loads, but the body where the component should be isn't loaded. I have tried various approaches, and I'm stumped. Can anyone generate a simple test application and verify that adding new routes works? I appreciate your time.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's more something to report to JHipster on github

Comment: Understood. I posted here in hopes there could be a learning discussion in the case I was doing something wrong, but I can take this question there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you solved this but I was having the same issue and what worked for me was to make sure that the route I was adding was above the route to `"/"` in the code.

Per this guide https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/primary-components routes should be ordered from more specific to less specific. I had my new route at the bottom of my route list in the code, but when I moved it above the `"/"` route definition, it worked.